# How to copy file from Windows laptop to Linux remote virtual server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, debian, scp

There are already quite a few topics on this issue here on SuperUser. However, I have spent the last 3 hours trying all of them, but am unable to fix this.

I am trying to copy a file from my laptop to a remote Linux server.

My laptop uses Windows 8.1, the remote server is Debian. I am connected to the Linux server via a PUTTY.

If I was using a Linux machine, it would be as easy as A-B-C. But, as my laptop is Windows... well...

Here is the command I've tried :

```
pscp C:\Users\Michael Storm\Desktop\Folder\public_key.ppk mstorm@my.linux.server:/home/mstorm
```

- mstorm --- my username on the linux server (and also my home-directory)
- public_key.ppk  --- the file I'm trying to copy to the linux server
- `C:\Users\Michael Storm\Desktop\Folder\public_key.ppk` --- the filepath (on my laptop)

(Just to be clear:  there is a space-break between `public_key.ppk` and `mstorm`. This forum carried over the second half of my command to the next line)

This command gave me the error:

> UNKNOWN COMMAND PSCPP

So, I changed "PSCP" to "SCP",  and I got the error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known Permission denied (publickey).
>   lost connection

Comment: simple solution; use WinSCP. just connect and copy the file over.

Comment: Although not related to the error: Arguments that contain spaces must be enclosed in quotes, like this: `pscp "C:\some path\file.txt" "user@host:/some folder"`.

Answer (score 5):

Make it easy on yourself and use WinSCP, WinSCP is an open source free SFTP client, FTP client Its main function is file transfer between a local and a remote computer. and integrates well with putty

[WIN SCP Download link](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

if you really want to use PSCP then to use pscp you will need to ensure you set path or command from putty folder where pscp.exe is i.e.

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\putty\directory;%PATH%
```

my set path was "set PATH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY;%pscp.exe% "

Answer (score 2):

Use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)!!.

---

**What is SFTP?**

> In computing, the SSH File Transfer Protocol (also Secure File
>   Transfer Protocol, or SFTP) is a network protocol that provides file
>   access, file transfer, and file management over any reliable data
>   stream.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)

---

**What is WinSCP?**

> WinSCP is an open source free SFTP client, FTP client, WebDAV client
>   and SCP client for Windows. Its main function is file transfer between
>   a local and a remote computer. Beyond this, WinSCP offers scripting
>   and basic file manager functionality.

Source [WinSCP Website](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction).

---

**How it works?.**

Just do the following steps.

- After install WinSCP just press Start Icon and search for the installed program.

[image]

- It will open the following screen, there just Press "New" Button.

[image]

- After that just select the Protocol at this case default is SFTP and fill the fiels with the following information.

  - In the **red box** put the IP Address or DNS name.
  - In the **orange** box put your Linux host User.
  - In the **green** put the password.
  - Then press **Connect**

[image]

- After that you will see a kinda **"commander"** window and there you can ***drag and drop*** between your windows and linux host.

[image]

---

> **P.S.**
>
> Srry my current configuration it's spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Set the PATH and then try, else first locate the file **pscp.exe** on cmd. you have to run the above command in same directory.

Example - if you have pscp.exe on your desktop, then run `cd C:\Users\<your_username>\Desktop` first and then run your command -

```
pscp C:\Users\Michael Storm\Desktop\Folder\public_key.ppk mstorm@my.linux.server:/home/mstorm
```

You can also give password here also, instead of giving later -

```
pscp -pw <password> C:\Users\Michael Storm\Desktop\Folder\public_key.ppk mstorm@my.linux.server:/home/mstorm
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution for this question using the Command Prompt in Windows.

The problem looks in the **'\'** in the command. Just replace **'\'** by **'/'** in Command Prompt and the command should work.

In your case, the command becomes:

```
pscp C:/Users/Michael Storm/Desktop/Folder/public_key.ppk mstorm@my.linux.server:/home/mstorm/Desktop
```